# Multiple datatypes for a field in schema python eve

Tags: python, database-schema, eve

I have a data model like the below(written in ruby):

```
"text": {"type":["string", "integer"], "minLength":1, "maxLength":30, "title": "Text"},
```

I have to convert this to a schema in python eve. I have a problem with the multiple data types for the "text" field. How do I achieve that in Eve?

Btw, Is it a good practice to have it like that?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own validation rule as you can read on eve documentation on the [link](http://docs.python-eve.org/en/latest/validation.html#custom-validation-rules).